# How to set up Azure DevOps Release Pipeline for ASP.NET Core hosted Blazor WebAssembly App?

Tags: blazor-webassembly, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am not able to set up an Azure DevOps Release Pipeline properly. I have a Blazor WebAssembly App (ASP.NET Core Hosted, client and server projects), the latest ASP.NET Core with the latest Entity Framework Core, Radzen controls, MS SQL, and Individual Accounts Authentication. On Azure, I have SQL Database and App Service. Can anyone have experience with how to do this?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. Can you add details to your question as code, error logs? You can take the [tour] and read [ask]